# Finished a set of activities, possibly in a task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

In my app I implement a set of tabs to show activities instead of switching between fragments. All of these activities have a back button that I want to take the user out of the tabbed set of activities to where they were before they got to those screens. Is there a way I can easily finish all of the activities representing the tabs?

I looked into tasks but it seems like you can't just destroy a task and instead you have to start an activity in that task using CLEAR_TOP or CLEAR_TASK or something similar.

EDIT:
We use activities instead of fragments because each tab will be very large and complex/fully featured sections of the app that we thought would be better suited to an activity. The activities are started with REORDER_TO_FRONT. We do not want to use CLEAR_TOP since we would have to do a lot of requerying of data everytime we switched tabs. So for an example of the problem flow:

- came from activity X and started activity A (the landing activity for the set of tabbed activities)
- click a tab and switch to activity B stack looks like X->A->B
- click third tab stack looks like X->A->B->C
- when we click a "back" button on screen, all three activities should be removed from the stack so it becomes just X. But if we call finish it will make the stack look like X->A->B which we do not want.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What code you already have, for example the Tabbed Activity?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you use Activities for your Tabs instead of Fragments?

Comment: Explain your navigation by example. Show what activites are on the stack in what order in the scenario where you want to "go back". It sounds like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will do what you want, but I need more information.